# PHP - "use($var)" not working in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to pass variable from one function to another and then to preg_replace_callback:

```
class Renderer
{
private static function make_query($q) {

    ...

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($c)) {
        $data = $r['title'];
        $finaltpl.=self::render($q[0]['template'],$data);
    }

    public static function render ($render,$d='') {
        echo 'var D is:'.$d.'<br>';
        $render = preg_replace_callback("/\[\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]\]/", function ($matches) use ($d) {
        return 'var D inside is:'.$d.'<br>';
            },$render
            );
    return $render;
}
```

But outside the replacer it works normally and echoes the var correctly, but inside it just shows $d as an empty string. Where can the problem be?

Comment: I have modified your code slightly (which makes it more like a [mcve]), and [it actually works](https://eval.in/699688).